# Java: Cast String to primitive type dynamically

Tags: java, reflection, casting

I want to invoke a method by reflection in java.

I have on my hand the [Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) instance of the method I want to invoke (so I can get the types of its parameters), in addition, I have the values of these parameters as Strings.

I have an assumption that all the parameters MUST be primitives.

for example, if I want to invoke the following method:

```
public static double calc(int a, double b, String op){...}
```

I have the parameter as a String Array:

```
String[]: {"25", "34.45", "add"}
```

So, how can I convert this String array to array that contains (int, double, string)?
I know that I can go over all the primitive types and try to parse the value in each type... Is there an easier way? something like "generic parse" method.

Comment: Generic parse ! Your requirement is not generic at all , parse each element as different data type is not generic !

Comment: you are right, I mentioned the reflection just to tell the motivation of what I want to do.

Comment: There is no such thing, at least standard implementation. But you can easily make your own: knowing method, find out parameter types, and in a loop, parse string representation according to the required parameter type.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'casting String to [a] primitive type'. You have to *convert.*

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't go over all the primitive types and try to parse the value in each type.

You should get the type of each argument from the `Method` instance, and based on the type of the argument, call the appropriate method to transform the String into the required type:  `Double.valueOf()` for a double (`Double.TYPE`), `Integer.valueOf()` for an int (`Integer.TYPE`), etc.

Comment: but here is the point, I don't have the types explicitly, I have them as a [Type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html) instances (which I get from `method.getParameterTypes()`), i.e. I don't know that the first one is int, the second is double and the last one is String

Comment: `if (type.equals(Integer.TYPE)) { arg = Integer.valueOf(s); } else if (type.equals(Double.TYPE)) { arg = Double.valueOf(s); }` ...

Comment: so I need to go over all the primitive types and do this... there is no shorter way?

Comment: I don't know of any other way. There are only 8 primitive types. Shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ConvertUtils` from `commons-beanutils`, see [`convert` method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/ConvertUtils.html#convert(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class)). You need to implement the loop over the array of types however...

Answer (score 1):

First your question IMHO has nothing to do with reflection. Primitive types cannot be instantiated using reflection. Reflection is for objects only.

> how can I convert this String array to array that contains (int,
>   double, string)?

You can't. An array in Java cannot contain different data types. A workaround would be to use `List<Object>`. The problem is that this will require casts later to retrieve the elements (with the possibility of getting a `ClassCastException`).

> Is there an easier way? something like "generic parse" method.

I don't know about anything like this in the standard library. And I doubt there's any because what should `"25"` parsed to? `int`? `long`? `float`? `BigInteger`? This is up to developer, so you have to write this yourself.

Comment: I didn't mean to convert the array itself, but to iterate its elements. regarding your second note, I mentioned that I have the type, i.e. I'm looking for a method that takes a String ("25") and Class<?> object that I want to convert to (int or Integer in this case) and it will return an Object (new Integer(25))

Comment: Oh I didn't see you have the Class for each parameter. My bad. Still your question has some confusing statements, like *"the parameters MUST be primitives"* but `String` is not a primitive. Also what I mean is that you can't get an array of different types but you can use a `List`.